# Is there a x64 version of the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure dll?

Tags: c#, wmi, .net-4.5, windows-7-x64

I'm new to WMI and so far, MSDN's documentation for WMI incites new projects to use the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure namespace instead of System.Management. Unfortunately, I can only find an x86 assembly of it and I would prefer an x64 version to allow the rest of my application to be x64 without having to IPC to a x86 subprocess just to bridge WMI.

I'm open to other solutions as well.

Comment: That cannot be accurate, Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll targets AnyCPU.  It does have a dependency on unmanaged code but that is spun off into a separate assembly, Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.dll.  You can see it when you look at the GAC on your machine, navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET \Assembly\GAC_64 and GAC_32.

Comment: Fantastic! I had the wrong dll all along. Thank you! I used the one in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET \Assembly\GAC_MSIL and it works! It's not any of the following I tried: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft ..., C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WMI\v1.0 ..., the nuget package, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64 ...

If you could make that an answer I'll accept it. Could you also link the documentation that says which one to use?

Comment: You need to use the one in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies.  This is only confusing because the VS installer flubs this and forgets to add the path to the registry.  So you need to use the Browse button in the Add Reference dialog to select it.  I don't know anything about documentation.

Comment: That's the first one I tried but I kept getting build errors or exceptions at run-time depending on the how i configured my projects. It did work when building strictly with x86 (not AnyCPU or x64).